# how can I add a wildcard with jquery binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

how can I add a wild card into this jquery bind event so that form fields with 'PauNumber' are ignored?  This field is repeated for each entity. Unfortunately I can't easily assign a css class to it because the text box is created server side.

many thanks

```
<div class="PassengerWrapper">
<input type="text" value="" name="PauNumber0" id="PauNumber0">
</div>

<div class="PassengerWrapper">
<input type="text" value="" name="PauNumber1" id="PauNumber1">
</div>

<div class="PassengerWrapper">
<input type="text" value="" name="PauNumber2" id="PauNumber2">
</div>

$('.PassengerWrapper input[type=text], .PassengerWrapper select').not(':hidden').each(function () {
```

Comment: What is 'PauNumber'? Is it class or name of a field?

Comment: what is 'PauNumber' a class ?

Comment: Your code doesn't bind any events - can you include *all* of the relevant parts, please?

Comment: You may want to read the doc : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Comment: sorry, please see above.  Hope that helps

Comment: Your code still appears incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it inside the .not('selector') to filter the elements you don't want

```
$('.PassengerWrapper input[type=text], .PassengerWrapper select').not(':hidden,input[name*=PauNumber]').each(function () {
```

You can use [name*=PauNumber] or [id*=PauNumber]

Here's an example fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/XQWmf/

Also link to the different [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: thank you, that looks great.  just waiting for testing analyst feedback before marking the comment.